# "Inliers" and "outliers" in French

Tags: terminologie, mathématiques

How do you say “inliers” and “outliers” (such as with the RANSAC stat method) in French? The RANSAC Wikipedia article doesn't translate them, but honestly there should be a translation since there is nothing English-ly-specific about these names.

So, how do we say “inliers” and “outliers” in French?

My guesses are “*Valeurs (ou données) centrales*” for inliers and "*Valeurs (ou données) éloignées*” for outliers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might translate them by *données plausibles* or *régulières* and *données aberrantes*.

Comment: On peut aussi parler de *mesures* _correctes_ VS mesures aberrantes, _atypiques_ (ce qui rejoindrait le terme "écart-type")

Comment: Ok je vais accepter cette réponse, cela me semble plausible. C'est toujours plus intéressant de parler avec des termes francophones avec ses collègues, même si les publications sont en Anglais.

Answer (score 1):

The usual french term for *outliers* is [*données aberrantes*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donn%C3%A9e_aberrante), but I do not know what (if any) is teh proper term for *inliers*.

Comment: Ok merci! :) En effet j'aurais du le voir, il est sur Wikipédia aussi...